# Prove for all integer $n > 1$ that if $n | 34$, then $n+5$ and $n^2+$9 are coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

My attempt was suppose $\gcd (n+5, n^2+9) = d$ where $d$ is an integer, hence $d|n+5$ and $d|n^2+9$ but I don't know how could I rearrange this to make it $1$

Comment: $1|34$ but $1+5=6$ and $1^2+0=10$ aren't coprime -- they share factor $2$; same with $17$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner A technically correct but ethically incorrect example :)

Comment: In my comment above, I meant $1^2+\color{red}9=10$; I object to my example being called ethically incorrect; besides, I actually gave two examples ($1$ and $17$)

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha: What is "ethically incorrect" in pointing out that $17$ is a counterexample to the claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is following. Since $n\in\{1,2,17,34\}$ check the statement for each $n$:

$$n=1: \gcd(6,10)=2$$

$$n=2: \gcd(7,13)=1$$

$$n=17: \gcd(22,298)=2$$

$$n=34: \gcd(39,1165)=1$$

So the statement is true only for even $n$.

---

"Hard way": Say exists prime $p\mid n+5$ and $p\mid n^2+9$, then $p\mid n^2-25$ so $$p\mid (n^2+9)-(n^2-25) = 34$$

This means $p= 2$ or $p=17$.

If $p=17$ we get $n+5\geq 17$ so $n=17$ or $n=34$ and thus $p\mid n$ so $p\mid 5$ which is not true.

Case $p=2$ is possible iff $n$ is odd.

Comment: why would d|n^2-25?

Comment: because $d|n+5$ and $(n-5)(n+5)=n^2-25$

Comment: I can't @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 1):

[Note: this answer presumes that the question intended $\,34\mid n,$ not $\,n\mid 34$ as written.]

Hint:

If $d$ divides both $n+5, n^2+9$

$d$ must divide $n^2+9-(n+5)(n-5)=34$

So, $(n+5,n^2-9)$ must divide $34$

But $34\mid n\implies(n+5,34)=1$

Comment: In other words you're tacitly assuming that $n\mid 34$ in the question was a typo for $34\mid n$? That sounds plausible, but the assumption should be stated explicitly in the answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, My idea: as $34$ divides $n,n$ is even $$\implies n+5,n^2+9$$ are both odd. Similarly, for $17$

Comment: x @lab: Are you overlooking that the question title states that $n$ divides $34$, not that $34$ divides $n$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I believe that's a typo