# Show for all integers $n$, if $d$ is an integer such that $d|(n+5)$ and $d|(n^2+7)$, then $d|32$

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

I have tried doing:

$$n+5=d*x$$
$$n^2+7=d*y$$
for x and y when they are both integers.
$$\frac{n+5}{x}=\frac{n^2+7}{y}$$
$$y(n+5)=x(n^2+7)$$

I am stuck here, does anyone know how to continue the proofing?
Thanks

Comment: For such problems much of the time all you need to know is that $d$ will divide multiples and sums of whatever you know $d$ already divides.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289844/if-i-know-that-b-is-a-multiple-of-32-then-how-can-i-show-that-b5-and-b2/3289846?noredirect=1#comment6766596_3289846

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that post?

Comment: Strange people @DerekLuna

Answer (score 4):

$d|n^2+7-(n+5)(n-5)$, where the right hand side is 32.

Comment: How do get to $$d|n^2+7−(n+5)(n−5)$$ Why subtract $$(n+5)(n-5)$$

Comment: Because after subtraction you are left with $d|32$.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution...

We note that $d|(n+5)\implies d|(n+5)^2\implies d|(n^2+10n+25)$, but $d|(n^2+7)$ and hence we get,$$d|(n^2+10n+25-(n^2+7))\implies d|(10n+18)$$Also, $d|(n+5)\implies d|(10n+50)$, but $d|(10n+18)$ and hence we get,$$d|(10n+50-(10n+18))\implies d|32$$This completes the proof...

Comment: I did the same then realized there was some $25 +7$ business.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the above technique always works. Just try to eliminate $n$...

Answer (score 1):

We know that:
$$d | n + 5, \quad d | n^2 + 7,\quad \Rightarrow d | (n+5)^2 - (n^2+7) = 10(n+5) - 32$$
This means that:
$$d | 10(n+5) - 32,\quad \Rightarrow d | 32$$
beacause $d | n+5$.

Comment: Who's the weirdo who is downvoting perfectly good answers?

Comment: Not me, but I am guessing it is because people are giving slightly different and longer ways to do the problem when there is the perfectly good answer by user negative one over twelve.

Comment: @DerekLuna Is there any meta post discussing that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $d|n+5$ and $d|n^2 +7$ then $d|j(n+5) + k(n^2 + 7)$ for all integers $j,k$.  So if we can find integers $j,k$ so that $j(n+5) + k(n^2 +7) = 32$ we'd be done.

We want to have the $n$ and $n^2$ terms cancel out and we can start to do that by considering multiplying then $n+5$ by $n$ and subtracting the $n^2 + 7$ term.

That is $n(n+5) - (n^2+7) = (n^2 + 5n) - (n^2 +7) = 5n+7$.

To get rid of the $5n$ we can subtract multiple $n+5$ by $-5$ so we can get:

$n(n+5) - (n^2 + 7) - 5(n+5) = (5n+7) - (5n+25)=-32$.  And to get the final result of $32$ we simply multiply the whole thing by $-1$.

$32 = -n(n+5) +(n^2 + 7) + 5(n+5) =(5-n)(n+5) + (n^2+7)$.

So if $j = (5-n)$ and $k = 1$ then

$d|j(n+5) + k(n^2 + 7) = (5-n)(n+5) + (n^2+7) = (25 - n^2) + (n^2 + 7) = 32$.

=====

To continue what you were doing:

$n + 5 = x\times d$ and $n^2 + 7 = y\times d$

So $-n^2 + 25 = (5-n)(n+5) = (5-n)xd$.

So $32 = (-n^2 + 25) + (n^2 + 7) = (5-n)xd + yd = [(5-n)x + y]d$.